# Why does the ending -な sometimes translate to "do" and sometimes translate to "do not"?

Tags: meaning

Why is the meaning of -na different in the two sentences below?

これを食べな - Don't eat this

ここに座りな - Sit here

Comment: The first means "eat this."

Comment: Do you mean 「食べるな」？

Comment: 食べな means "Eat this" and 食べ**ん**な (or 食べるな) means "Don't eat this". 座りな is "Sit", 座るな is "Don't sit", and 座んな is either "Sit" and "Don't sit" depending on the context!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Especially Naruto's answer which fully explains the logic in the grammar. I found the strange translation -これを食べな - Don't eat this- in Duolingo and when I checked it in DeepL it was the same answer, but when I check DeepL today the translation is changed to "eat this". Thanks a lot for your quick support.